# A question about contestants linked with combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose A and B are two candidates contested in an election who secured 11 and 7 votes respectively. Then the number of ways if A stayed ahead of B throughout the counting process of votes is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269623/number-of-paths-that-lie-under-the-diagonal

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to see the website link