# What is the probability that the path does not cross the grid's diagonal?

Tags: probability

Suppose you wish to travel from the bottom left corner to the top right corner of an 8×8 grid by moving either one unit up or one unit right at a time. What is the probability that the path you take does not cross the grid’s diagonal?

Comment: The bottom left corner in part of the diagonal itself, isnt it ?

Comment: @Vanwij yes . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is twice the "Catalan number" $C_8$:
>
> $2 C_8=2 \dfrac{1}{9}\binom{16}{8}$.

See this wonderfully illustrated [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) where you will find "$C_n$ is the number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with n × n square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal".

(we have to count it twice because we must take into account paths that are **above** the diagonal).

A generalization : [Number of paths that lie under the diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269623).